# Constructor help in java

Tags: java, constructor

Working on an assignment and i am having an issue figuring out how to properly make a constructor and successfully make an object.

```
public class CDAssignment {

    public CD(String artist, String title){
        artist = "Awesomeguy";
        title = "AwesomeCDName";
        tracklist myTracklist = new tracklist(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
        String artist;
        String title;
    }
}
```

I have some other methods in there right now, but they are irrelevant.
Im going to be making another class for the tracklist constructor. I know how to do that.
My program keeps telling me that i dont have a return type for the method, but im not trying to make a method, im trying to make a constructor.

Comment: constructor must have the same name of your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constructor must have the same name as the class itself **Edit: and you should assign the member with the parameters**:

```
    public CDAssignment(String artist, String title){
        this.artist = artist;
        this.title = title;
        tracklist myTracklist = new tracklist(100);
    }
```

And then in main:

```
CDAssignment myCD = new CDAssignment("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
```

Also if you want `artist` and `title` to be member variables of your class, you need to declare them out of any function.

```
public class CDAssignment {

    String artist;
    String title;
```

Comment: freakin superman over here. thanks man. haha

Comment: What about assigning the parameters ...?

Comment: cant accept your answer for another 12 minutes

Comment: @BheshGurung yes, I was editing my answer to say the members should be declared outside of main to be assigned in the constructor.

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean now. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to have the same name as your class:

```
public class CDAssignment {

    public CDAssignment(String artist, String title){  // <-- note change
        artist = "Awesomeguy";
        title = "AwesomeCDName";
        tracklist myTracklist = new tracklist(100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CD myCD = new CD("Awesomeguy", "AwesomeCDName");
        String artist;
        String title;
    }
}
```